# Multiple matches separated by space

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm working on a script that finds ipv4 matches in a `.txt` file.
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash


        if [ -e $1 ]
        then
                grep -Eow '(^| )(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($|[[:space:]]) ' $1

        else
                echo "fisierul nu a fost gasit"

        fi
```

The only problem I'm having is that when there are 2 IP addresses separated by a space just the first one get printed.For exemple:
`12.168.7.4 3.4.2.5`.In this exemple just `12.168.7.4` is printed and the second one is ignored.If I'm using 2 spaces both addresses will be printed.Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Use `grep -Po '(?<!\S)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?!\S)' $1`

Answer (score 0):

Try using below command :

```
grep -E  "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" $1
```

Comment: The regex in the question limits the numbers to 0-255, whereas this regex allows any three digit number. It also doesn't prevent matching something like `1111.1.1.1111` with first/last octet being longer than 3 digits.